# best way to loop through and combine products

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, foreach, cgi

I'm looking for your personal thoughts on the best way to do this as there a number of ways that I can see to get to the same end.

I have a store front that has multiple different booklets that can be ordered in any combination.

Each booklet item has L x W x H and weight in the database.  They're all really the same L x W, it's the thickness and weight that varies.

I also have a set max box size.

I know I can fit a height of 10.5 in the largest box size.

I can combine the books however for shipping.  So I want to fill the box to the max I can, then repeat until I only have a partial box.

The final result I need is an array of each of the boxes and their weight.

Example:

**Items ordered**

1. 100 of Book 1 with a thickness of .05 and weight of .15
2. 200 of Book 2 with a thickness of .07 and a weight of .23

**Heights**

1. 100 * .05 = 5
2. 200 * .07 = 14

**Weights**

1. 100 * .15 = 15
2. 200 * .23 = 46

Box 1 Contains

1. 150 of Book 2
2. Height: 150 * .07 = 10.5
3. Weight: 150 * .23 = 34.5

Box 2 Contains

1. 50 of Book 2 and 100 of Book 1
2. Height: (100 * .05) + (50 * .07) = 8.5
3. Weight: (100 * .15) + (50 * .25) = 27.5

How would you go about looping through the information to get the output?
Start with one product, figure the height, divide it out to full boxes, calculate the weight of those boxes and add each full box to the array, take the height of the partial box and move on to the next product?  Or......??

Static coding would be "easy", but I'm trying to code this dynamically so that I don't have to come back in every time I add a new product.

-edit-

Here is my current loop, but this is only totaling the quantity and dividing into boxes.  The current products are all the same size / shape, so this worked fine then.

```cgi
    if($zip_code != '')
    {
        my $item_list = enc_sql_select_multi("SELECT * FROM `$PREF{shopping_carts_table}` WHERE `cart_id` = '$cart_id' AND `sold` = '0' AND `deleted_from_cart` = '0'");
        my $item_qty = '0';
        foreach my $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %$item_list)
        {
            $item_qty =~ s/,//g;
            my $item_id = $$item_list{$k}{id};
            my $item_qty_new = $$item_list{$k}{option1value};
            $item_qty_new =~ s/,//g;
            $item_qty = $item_qty + $item_qty_new;
        }
        if ($item_qty != '0')
            {
                $item_qty =~ s/,//g;
                if ( $item_qty == 25 )
                {
                    my $tempCount = $carton_specs{25}{boxNo};
                    $tempCount++;
                    $carton_specs{25}{boxNo} = $tempCount;
                }
                elsif ( $item_qty == 50 )
                {
                    my $tempCount = $carton_specs{50}{boxNo};
                    $tempCount++;
                    $carton_specs{50}{boxNo} = $tempCount;
                }
                elsif ( $item_qty == 100 )
                {
                    my $tempCount = $carton_specs{100}{boxNo};
                    $tempCount++;
                    $carton_specs{100}{boxNo} = $tempCount;
                }
                elsif ($item_qty > 100 && $item_qty < 5000)
                {
                    my $fullBoxCt = int($item_qty / 200);
                    my $tempCountFull = $carton_specs{200}{boxNo};
                    $tempCountFull = $tempCountFull + $fullBoxCt;
                    $carton_specs{200}{boxNo} = $tempCountFull;
                    my $partBoxQty = $item_qty - (200 * $fullBoxCt);
                    if ($partBoxQty != 0)
                    {
                        my $tempCountPart = $carton_specs{$partBoxQty}{boxNo};
                        $tempCountPart++;
                        $carton_specs{$partBoxQty}{boxNo} = $tempCountPart;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    @shipDetails =
                    (
                        {
                            Code => 1000,
                            Price => '0.00'
                        },
                        {
                            Code => 1500,
                            Price => '0.00'
                        }
                    );
                    return (@shipDetails);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no getting away from this being a classic example of the bin-packing problem and while I am no mathematician either, a lot of people who are have given this considerable thought. So:

There is no known *optimal* solution to this problem that can be computed in polynomial time and it would appear the size of your inputs can be quite large. Therefore, you should adopt one of the following heuristics:

1. `First Fit Algorithm`: Process the booklets one by one placing it in the first box that has enough capacity to hold the booklet. If there are no such boxes, a new box must be started and added to the list of boxes available.
2. `Best Fit Algorithm`: Process the booklets one by one placing it in the box where it fits the tightest (has the smallest capacity left). If there are no boxes that can hold the booklet, a new box must be started and added to the list of boxes available.
3. `First Fit Decreasing Algorithm`: First order the booklets by decreasing height and then perform the First Fit Algorithm. In your example you would be packing up the "Book 2" booklets first.
4. `Best Fit Decreasing Algorithm`: First order the booklets by decreasing height and then perform the Best Fit Algorithm.

But, of course, your orders consist of N items of of a certain type of booklet. We will take the prescription "one at a time" in the above algorithms loosely. So if you are doing, for example, the First Fit Algorithm, then when you find the first box that has the capacity to hold the booklet, it is easy enough to calculate the maximum number of those booklets, M, that box could hold and process up to `min(M, N_LEFT)` booklets at one time where `N_LEFT` is the number of booklets of that size you still have left to pack up. Likewise for any of the other three algorithms.

You can survey other bin-packing heuristics of which the above are just a sample four. I can't say one is necessarily superior to the others in all cases. I think any reasonable implementation of any of them will be satisfactory for your purposes. Anyway, this is my take.

Comment: ok, that's a lot easier to understand than the other articles.  And pretty much confirms what I had figured out.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!  I'm probably going to go with the First Fit option and just cycle through the items in the order.  Still not "optimal" if they reach a point where they want to add items that aren't the same size booklet but better than the static coding I have now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20bin%20packing%20problem,a%20combinatorial%20NP%2Dhard%20problem.). The best optimal algorithm is [Korf's](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/13/Papers/103.pdf). If this is too slow for the amount of data you have, there are various algorithms that provide good approximate answers faster.

Comment: Both those articles are fascinating, but I'm not a mathematician, and they don't really tell me how to optimize a coding loop to figure out what will fit in a box.  I know that pack-out can be very in-depth, and there are programs out there with all that complex math to optimize freight and all kinds of things.  However, I know 2 of the dimensions, I just need to figure out how many total items, and how many boxes based on the height and what can fit in a box.  I have a couple ideas, what I'm looking for is someone else's take on it.